# how to update a existing csv file with another csv with different structure using php

Tags: php, csv

hi i have 2 different csv file. both are having different formats of columns. one from which i have to collect the data is like

A(contains) - Catelog,  B(contains) - Productno,  C(contains) -  Rate,   D(contains)  -  Size,  E(contains)  -  Category  and many more...

and the second in which i have to add the data is like

A(contains) - sku, B(contains) - Store, C(contains) - attribute, D(contains) - Type, E(contains) - root_category...and many more..

i would like to know , how can i add all the columns from sheet one in to sheet two after column C (attribute)..into D,E,F..and also not removing those already existing.

Comment: Do you need any merging according to a common column?

Comment: What are you using, [tag:PHP] or [tag:Excel]?

Comment: i dont have any comman column yet. need to create new column in the second sheet and aslo by not replacing the original ones.using PHP